# split a comma-separated string and add Quotes in C# - elegant solution

Tags: c#, string

I have a `string` looking like this:

```
var v = "10,14,18,21"
```

and would like to use it as something looking like this:

```
'10', '14', '18', '21'
```

I have a written a function which splits the values by *comma* and add them back together as a string. Additionally I remove the last `,` from the result string.

I put everything in a function called `prep` for testing.

The function does, what I want it to do. However, I was wondering if there is a **more elegant** way to achieve the same result. Here's what I came up with:

```
public static string prep(string s) {
    string res = "";

    List<string> list = s.Split(',').ToList<string>();

    foreach(var item in list) 
        res += "'" + item + "',";

    res = res.TrimEnd(',');

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Lots - this is very ineffective as each string operation creates a *new* temporary string. You can simply replace all `,` with `','`. You can use `String.Join` instead of `+=`. This will use a StringBuilder internally to avoid temporary strings. You can use the StringBuilder directly. Or you can use a Regex to replace the *words* with quoted ones. This is probably the fastest and shortest way as no temporary strings are generated

Comment: There is a [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join) method that inserts separators between the parts - no need to trim the last one off

Comment: I assume your string is `var v = "10,14,18,21";` and not `"var v = 10,14,18,21"`?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, my bad.  your assumtion is right

Comment: Also should be noted that you don't need the `ToList`, you can just iterate over the resulting array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) here:

```
var result = string.Join(", ", v.Split(",").Select(x => $"'{x}'"));

Console.WriteLine(result);
// '10', '14', '18', '21'
```

Which basically concatenates the items by `", "`, then projects single quotes around each string with [`Enumerable.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) from LINQ.

You can also add single quotes without [$ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

```
var result = string.Join(", ", v.Split(",").Select(x => "'" + x + "'"));
```

As [@Racil Hilan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61115548/split-a-comma-separated-string-and-add-quotes-in-c-sharp-elegant-solution/61115643#comment108120871_61115643) helpfully pointed out in the comments, we don't need LINQ here and can just surround the result with `"'"` and join on `"', '"`:

```
var result = "'" + string.Join("', '", v.Split(",")) + "'";
```

Comment: This generates multiple temporary strings, unlike Enigmativity's solution which only creates one temporary string, and Dmitry Bychenko which creates *no* temporary strings.

Comment: Also using LINQ here is like killing a fly with a hammer. You're already splitting and then joining, simply join on `','` (a comma surrounded with apostrophes) and then surround the result with apostrophes, no LINQ needed.

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered this?

```
var v = "10,14,18,21";
var r = $"'{v.Replace(",", "', '")}'";
```

That gives: `'10', '14', '18', '21'`

Answer (score 6):

You can try *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string result = Regex.Replace(v, "[^,]+", " '$0'");
```

here we wrap every item between commas into single quotes.

**Edit:** As juharr pointed out in the comments, we have *extra space* at the beginning of the `result` string. We can either

remove it:

```
result = Regex.Replace(v, "[^,]+", " '$0'").TrimStart();
```

Or prevent it:

```
string result = Regex
 .Replace(v, "[^,]+", m => $"{(m.Index > 0 ? " ":"")}'{m.Value}'");
```

Comment: That's *the* most efficient and fastest solution. No temporary strings involved, no LINQ.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No temporary strings are visible strings in this code, but what about the temporary objects inside Regex.Replace?

Comment: This results in an extra space at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually after some testing this is actually the slowest solution (because of course regex is slower).  If you use the `RegexOptions.Compiled` it gets better and scales better than some of the other solutions, but still doesn't beat `string.Replace` in time complexity, space complexity might be a different issue though.

Comment: Correction: this is not worse than the Aggergate solution.  That one is way way worse.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've just run benchmark with solutions from answers here https://imgur.com/a/El1vibG The regex is 10x slower then `Replace` and 3x slower then Linq solution. It also has the same memory comparison

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski all LINQ solutions generate temporary strings. Have you tried creating just *one* regex and reuse it? You may be looking at the time and allocations of creating the regex, not executing it. I had to parse a pretty large log file (several MBs) and using a regex was an order of magnitude faster and more efficient than ReadLines and splitting. In fact, I gave up on my initial attempt to use parallelisation because using a single Regex instance ended up being as fast as the paralleled splitting version.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos One of my tests uses a single compiled regex and it's still worse.  I have very rarely seen regex out perform a well crafted solution that uses string methods instead.  In fact when I do use regex it's because I'm willing to make the speed trade off if the regex is less complicated than the code.  I'd say your experience was an outlier and not typical of comparing regex solutions to solutions using string methods.

Comment: @juharr your test doesn't count the GC overhead because 10K iterations are too few. The stopwatch won't detect the GC overhead either. BenchmarkDotNet on the other hand measures all these things. It's the GC overhead that makes string operations **before the Span optimizations** expensive. Then again,  I'm typically using regex to extract parts of log records, so splitting or substring operations generate waste no matter what. This question's string replacement though uses and reproduces the entire string.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) on the result of `Split`, then [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8):

```
public static string prep(string s) {
    var array = s.Split(',');
    // Select takes a lambda that tells it what to do with each item in the array
    var quotesAdded = array.Select(x => $"'{x}'");
    var result = string.Join(", ", quotesAdded);
    return result;
}
```

Or all in an [expression-bodied member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members):

```
public static string prep(string s) => string.Join(", ",
    s.Split(',').Select(x => $"'{x}'")
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the heck of it I wrote some code to test out the various methods here to see how they fair against each other with different length strings.  Feel free to add any other variations to this to find out for yourself which one is fastest and to see how it scales with larger strings.

Note: I gave up on a string with 10,000 comma separated items because the Aggregate method was taking a very long time to complete.

```
private static readonly Random Rand = new Random();

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int size = 10; size <= 1000; size *= 10)
    {
        var input = GenerateInput(size);

        Console.WriteLine($"Size {size}:");
        Console.WriteLine("Average          Total            Method");
        Tester(input, AddSingleQuotesRegExNotCompiled, nameof(AddSingleQuotesRegExNotCompiled));
        Tester(input, AddSingleQuotesRegExCompiled, nameof(AddSingleQuotesRegExCompiled));
        Tester(input, AddSingleQuotesStringReplace, nameof(AddSingleQuotesStringReplace));
        Tester(input, AddSingleQuotesJoinSplitSelectWithInterpolation, nameof(AddSingleQuotesJoinSplitSelectWithInterpolation));
        Tester(input, AddSingleQuotesJoinSplitSelectWithoutInterpolation, nameof(AddSingleQuotesJoinSplitSelectWithoutInterpolation));
        Tester(input, AddSingleQuotesJoinSplit, nameof(AddSingleQuotesJoinSplit));
        Tester(input, AddSingleQuotesSplitSelectAggregate, nameof(AddSingleQuotesSplitSelectAggregate));

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}


public static void Tester(string input, Func<string, string> func, string name)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        func(input);
    }

    sw.Stop();

    Console.Write($"{sw.Elapsed/10000} {sw.Elapsed} {name}");
    Console.WriteLine();
}

public static string GenerateInput(int count)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (count-- > 0)
    {
        builder.Append(Rand.Next(100));
        if (count > 0)
            builder.Append(',');
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}

private static Regex addComma = new Regex("[^,]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);

public static string AddSingleQuotesRegExCompiled(string input) => 
    addComma.Replace(input, "'$0'");
public static string AddSingleQuotesRegExNotCompiled(string input) => 
    Regex.Replace(input, "[^,]+", " '$0'");
public static string AddSingleQuotesStringReplace(string input) => 
    $"'{input.Replace(",", ", ")}'";
public static string AddSingleQuotesJoinSplitSelectWithInterpolation(string input) => 
    string.Join(", ", input.Split(",").Select(x => $"'{x}'"));
public static string AddSingleQuotesJoinSplitSelectWithoutInterpolation(string input) => 
    string.Join(", ", input.Split(",").Select(x => "'" + x + "'"));
public static string AddSingleQuotesJoinSplit(string input) => 
    "'" + string.Join("', '", input.Split(",")) + "'";
public static string AddSingleQuotesSplitSelectAggregate(string input) => 
    input.Split(',')
        .Select(m => "'" + m + "'")
        .Aggregate((tot,next) => tot + "," + next);
}
```

with the following results

```
Size 10:
Average          Total            Method
00:00:00.0000053 00:00:00.0526194 AddSingleQuotesRegExNotCompiled
00:00:00.0000031 00:00:00.0309486 AddSingleQuotesRegExCompiled
00:00:00.0000002 00:00:00.0018592 AddSingleQuotesStringReplace
00:00:00.0000017 00:00:00.0169309 AddSingleQuotesJoinSplitSelectWithInterpolation
00:00:00.0000008 00:00:00.0084822 AddSingleQuotesJoinSplitSelectWithoutInterpolation
00:00:00.0000004 00:00:00.0039672 AddSingleQuotesJoinSplit
00:00:00.0000010 00:00:00.0102010 AddSingleQuotesSplitSelectAggregate

Size 100:
Total            Average          Method
00:00:00.0000239 00:00:00.2394021 AddSingleQuotesRegExNotCompiled
00:00:00.0000163 00:00:00.1628607 AddSingleQuotesRegExCompiled
00:00:00.0000015 00:00:00.0149009 AddSingleQuotesStringReplace
00:00:00.0000065 00:00:00.0650797 AddSingleQuotesJoinSplitSelectWithInterpolation
00:00:00.0000069 00:00:00.0693588 AddSingleQuotesJoinSplitSelectWithoutInterpolation
00:00:00.0000034 00:00:00.0338554 AddSingleQuotesJoinSplit
00:00:00.0000129 00:00:00.1287369 AddSingleQuotesSplitSelectAggregate

Size 1000:
Total            Average          Method
00:00:00.0002089 00:00:02.0892826 AddSingleQuotesRegExNotCompiled
00:00:00.0001607 00:00:01.6066026 AddSingleQuotesRegExCompiled
00:00:00.0000144 00:00:00.1444781 AddSingleQuotesStringReplace
00:00:00.0000578 00:00:00.5776627 AddSingleQuotesJoinSplitSelectWithInterpolation
00:00:00.0000580 00:00:00.5801025 AddSingleQuotesJoinSplitSelectWithoutInterpolation
00:00:00.0000296 00:00:00.2957712 AddSingleQuotesJoinSplit
00:00:00.0005631 00:00:05.6307457 AddSingleQuotesSplitSelectAggregate
```

Comment: This code doesn't measure the temp string and GC overhead that causes most of the delays when using string operations. I suspect repeating the tests using BenchmarkDotNet will generate different results. What this *does* show though, is that parsing the regex pattern in Regex.Replace accounts for 2/3 of the overall time

Answer (score 2):

Just another approach to solve this problem (without using LINQ):

```
public static string prep(string s) =>
    "'" + string.Join("', '", s.Split(",")) + "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use aggregate

```
    string a = "1,2,3,4,5";
    string c = a.Split(',').Select(m => "'" + m + "'").Aggregate((tot,next) => tot + "," + next);
```

Comment: That's far worse than the original in terms of wasted temporary strings. Never mind the LINQ overhead. To avoid all the temps you could get rid of `Select` (which offers nothing anyway), pass around a StringBuilder as the aggregated value and append quotes and strings to it

Comment: The OP gave a specific example string. It would make sense to use that in your answer and to show your actual output.