# comma separated list items with brackets in linq

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list and I want the comma separated of the items with item inside the []

Input is

```
List<string> inputString = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
```

output:

```
 [1],[2],[3],[4]
```

Can anybody let me know how to achieve this without foreach loop.
I want to use linq query.

I have tried below steps but not working

```
inputString.Aggregate("", (str1, str2) => '[' + str1+ ']' + "," + '[' + str2+ ']');
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61115548/split-a-comma-separated-string-and-add-quotes-in-c-sharp-elegant-solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you were originally trying with aggregate :

```
var results = inputString.Select(x => "[" + x + "]")
                         .Aggregate((cur,next) => cur + "," + next);
```

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2itoal)

Your attemp was not far off. Its result was `[[[1],[2]],[3]],[4]`.
element 1 + element 2, then element 1/2 + element 3. etc..
You just have to compute the `[x]` befor doing the elements aggregation.

nb: It's not the most effective way to concatenate, it will be the worst compare to String.Join

Answer (score 5):

Do you consider solving this problem without using `LINQ`?

If yes, then the next approach can be used:

```
List<string> inputString = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
string output = "[" + string.Join("],[", inputString) + "]";
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) method for that, then use [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1) to create a single result string

```cs
List<string> inputString = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
var result = string.Join(",", inputString.Select(s => $"[{s}]"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Approach with `Join()` combined with `Select()`

```
List<string> inputString = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
string result = string.Join(",", inputString.Select(x => '[' + x + ']'));
```

or just with `Join`

```
string result = "[" + string.Join("],[", inputString) + "]";
```

Answer (score 0):

or even if we want as much linq as possible

```cs
var result = inputString.Select(el => $"[{el}],").Aggregate("",(el1,el2)  => el1 + el2).TrimEnd(',');
```

Answer (score -1):

Even simpler with string interpolation.

```
string result = $"[{String.Join("],[", inputString)}]";
```